# How to execute the .exe which code by opengl in Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, opengl

Here, I have some sample code which are tutorials for OpenGL. They are developed in Visual Stdio 2008 or 2010. Now, I want to execute the .exe through by wine. How to do that?

Comment: What about running `wine [file name of your program].exe`?

Comment: err:dc:CreateDCW no driver found for L":0.0"
freeglut : fghInitialize: CreateDC failed, Screen size info may be incorrect
This is quite likely caused by a bad '-display' parameter
err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed
freeglut : Unable to create OpenGL 3.2 context (flags 0, profile 1)

Comment: @Gapry Does your graphics card/driver support OpenGL?

Comment: Yes, it is support openGL and I can develop through it.
gcc -o demo demo.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install `wine` and `winetricks`.

```
apt-get install wine winetricks
```

You can then use winetricks to install the DLLs required to run the binaries

```
# not as root
winetricks vcrun2008
winetricks vcrun2010
```

You should be able to launch your application with `wine <prog.exe>`. You should note there is no guarantee that `wine` will be able to run it properly.

Comment: I've test. It is not a solution. And, I just want to execute the .exe, not use the wine to execute VC then develop by it

Comment: @gapry the vcrun package have nothing to do with development. They install shared libraries required by most software written in .net.

Comment: I think so. I need to solve the linking problem if I need to do it.

Comment: Then, it become to how to use the .dll on Linux. It seem to be complex.

Answer (score 1):

If @jordanm's answer doesn't satisfy you, there is *no* way of doing what you ask.

Those tutorials you followed and compiled are -- by your own admission -- for Microsoft Visual Studio, and I can't help but note you didn't mention which actual programming language you used.

If you want to run openGL software on Linux, you'll need to compile it against linux-native openGL libraries.

I'd recommend starting [here](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics) if you're serious about developing openGL software in linux.